# BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I keep getting this response"BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR" when testing my in-app Subscription.

I generated signed apk of my app in release mode and uploaded on google play for alpha testing. I followed this tutorial
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#0
It is working fine when testing for static response for "android.test.purchased" product. but giving above response when testing my Subscriptions.

this is the code where i getting this response

```
mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
                if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
                    if (executeOnSuccess != null) {
                        executeOnSuccess.run();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
            }
        });
```

also, when i uploaded my apk, google asked if i want to opt-in for "Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)" so i did...
I read some solutions for my problem but all these involve one step that is "App signing" but i can't do anything there now:
https://ibb.co/d71LvCK.

i created test user too, and got link to download my app. i'm testing my app with same user. (of course different than my play store account)
Please help, thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128537/in-app-billing-v3-billing-response-result-developer-error

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In app billing v3 - BILLING\_RESPONSE\_RESULT\_DEVELOPER\_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128537/in-app-billing-v3-billing-response-result-developer-error)

Answer (score 2):

Clear you Google Play Store app cache in settings, took me a while to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

[The docs say](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference):

> BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR: Invalid arguments provided to the API. This error can also indicate that the application was not correctly signed or properly set up for Google Play Billing, or does not have the necessary permissions in its manifest

So this indicates that some error is being made when calling the API.

Possible errors:

- using the developer account instead of a separate tester gmail account (you said you aren't doing this)
- Are you definitely testing with the APK from the Play store alpha channel, not the one built from your IDE? If Play is signing your app which it is, then you need to test with the one downloaded from the Alpha channel on the Play store using the Google Play app to install, not from the one signed by your IDE

Comment: I didn't find solution there, neither i'm using that code.
Please look at tutorial link i shared above.
and I'm using different test account.

Comment: thanks for reply,
 Yes sir i'm, just now i uninstalled my app from phone and downloaded again from play strore to check, still same error.